# 'Chargeable': Where else, besides Singapore, is this word commonly used in this particular context?

Tags: word-usage, singapore-english

In Singapore, the word *chargeable* is used in the sense of it being something that can be charged for. Example:

> Customer asks, "Is the green tea free?"
>
> Waitress responds, "Sorry no, it is chargeable. $1 per person, free flow."

Another example is given by Singapore's tax authority, which refers to ([*chargeable income*](https://www.iras.gov.sg/irashome/Individuals/Locals/Working-Out-Your-Taxes/Income-Tax-Rates/)).

My question is: Is this commonly used anywhere else in the world?

And my follow-up question is: If I used this word in this context in the main Anglo-Saxon countries (US, UK, Canada, Australia, NZ), would I be readily understood?

Comment: In the US, the waiter or waitress might say "No, we charge for it."  But not *chargeable*.

Answer (score 4):

It has a legalese/bureaucratese flavour to it but it is used in the UK. Some  examples:

- Law: [Taxation of Chargeable Gains Act 1992](http://www.legislation.gov.uk/ukpga/1992/12/enacted)
- Hotel rules: [On-site parking is chargeable at...](http://www.premierinn.com/en/hotel/LONBLE/london-bexleyheath)
- "cleaning is chargeable against the deposit"
- "costs are chargeable against the debtor" (certainly this one is also US)

So for your follow-up: yes you'd be understood, but you'd sound like a pompous jobsworth.

Answer (score 1):

The UK would say "taxable income", if you are talking about income on which tax must be paid. Chargeable does not sound like that to me, but like something else, like deductible expenses. On the other hand, we would all understand about the chargeable green tea.

Comment: But we wouldn't use the expression.

Answer (score 1):

In AmE, in the context or 'gratis' vs paid service, 'chargeable' does not mean 'not cost free'. It doesn't sound totally wrong, just we would never think of saying that.

To the hearer, in that same context, you'd totally be understood (in an identical conversation). One would wonder where you came up with that word, but it would be understood what you intended.

For tax or legal purposes in the US, I think the corresponding term is 'taxable income'; most tax accounting vocabulary is already opaque or misleading enough.

Comment: (-1) Chargeable is most certainly an AmE word, just not common or used in the Singaporean way, I knew the word from chargeable vs non-chargeable Interstate highways. The former, which is mileage-limited, has a larger Federal subsidy. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interstate_Highway_System

Comment: @AndrewLazarus edited to remove the tendentious 'not a word'.

Comment: And -1 removed.

Answer (score 1):

In U.S. English, one of the most frequent contexts in which *chargeable* appears is in connection with the phrase "chargeable offense," meaning a violation of the law that is grounds for pressing criminal charges against the offender. A Google Books search turns up more than 250 matches for "chargeable offense," and a Google Ngram chart for the phrase over the period 1950–2005 looks like this:

[image]

Another term that has some currency in U.S. English is "chargeable expense," which, according to Charles Sweetland, [*Real Estate Accounting*](https://books.google.com/books?id=_DoUAQAAMAAJ&pg=PA19&dq=%22chargeable+expense%22&hl=en&sa=X&ei=e8JsVZ6TOcr8yQTA5oHoAQ&ved=0CEcQ6AEwBw#v=onepage&q=%22chargeable%20expense%22&f=false) (1909) had this meaning in early-twentieth-century accounting:

> The **chargeable expense** is that amount that can be or should be charged against the land contract, and this amount should be either posted to the individual account in the general ledger (if one is carried) or to the land contract ledger.

A more recent discussion of *chargeable expenses* appears in [*California Lawyer*](https://books.google.com/books?id=j3M8AQAAIAAJ&q=%22chargeable+expense%22&dq=%22chargeable+expense%22&hl=en&sa=X&ei=1sRsVYDTIIPRtQXi74GgBg&ved=0CEQQ6AEwCDgK), volume 12 (1992) [combined snippets]:

> General and administrative expenses are allocated based upon the ratio of the non-chargeable expense to total **chargeable** and non-chargeable **expense**. All expenses not considered non-chargeable are chargeable and include the following:
>
> • Regulation of the legal profession.
>
> • Improving the quality of legal services through the admissions process, attorney discipline, education and development of codes of conduct.
>
> • Making evaluations of judicial candidates.
>
> • Advising the legislature on pending bills with legal ramifications.

The term appears to be well established in India, too. From S. K. Chekraborty, [*Cost Accounting And Financial Management*](https://books.google.com/books?id=X45Fbw8RAgUC&pg=PA30&dq=%22chargeable+expense%22&hl=en&sa=X&ei=QcZsVeS4Co7UoASrpoCABg&ved=0CDsQ6AEwBg#v=onepage&q=%22chargeable%20expense%22&f=false) (New Delhi, 2004):

> **Chargeable expense :** Such expenses are directly charged or allocated to jobs, processes, products, cost centres or cost units. These are also called 'direct expenses'. These are "costs other than material and wages which are incurred for a specific product or saleable services".

So *chargeable* is readily understood in both legal and accounting contexts in the United States; but as other answerers have indicated, it isn't a term you would expect to hear (in this country) from a cashier or a waiter in a retail context.